# Possibility of loading html data in hidden field for PHP Form

Tags: php, html, hidden-field

Is it possible to load HTML into a hidden field when posting data in a php form?

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pdf_data" name="pdf_data" value="<div>test value <span id="test">test span</span></div>" />
```

Or will there be any issues I'm not seeing when I do this? I am getting permission error when I try directly loading the html onto the hidden field and submitting the form.

EDIT:
I would assume that the qoutation marks are causing the issue, is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: I would assume that the quotation marks are causing the issue?

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="pdf_data" name="pdf_data" value="<div>test value <span id='test'>test span</span></div>" /> OR <input type="hidden" id="pdf_data" name="pdf_data" value="<div>test value <span id=\"test\">test span</span></div>" />

Answer (score 1):

I think u getting error due to the quotation marks. Try to use as below that can solve your issue.

```
value="<div>test value <span id='test'>test span</span></div>"
```